# Adding an address to formula VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to update a formula by adding in some cell addresses, but when I run it, I get a Type mismatch error after the first increment.

EDIT: The Error has been spotted, it was working but there was another problem in another sheet, with a date going rogue and changing into a #N/A for no reason I can find. Anyway, my question now: for i=1 to 3, I get =0+$X$3+$AI$3+$AT$3+$BE$3+$BP$3+$CA$3 as a result. How do I get rid of the $ surrounding my letters? I want to stretch that formula. I know that by just clicking on the cell and pressing 3 times F4 I will get rid of all the $, but is there an automatic way of doing it?
 Here is my code:

```
Public Sub test3()

Dim i As Integer

With Sheet10

.Cells(3, 13).Formula = "=0"

For i = 1 To 100
If .Cells(1, 22 * i - 8) <> 0 Then

.Cells(3, 13).Formula = .Cells(3, 13).Formula & "+" & .Cells(3, 22 * i + 2).Address

 End If

 If .Cells(1, 22 * i + 3) <> 0 Then

.Cells(3, 13).Formula = .Cells(3, 13).Formula & "+" & .Cells(3, 22 * i + 13).Address

End If

Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This code works fine for me. Perhaps you have a bad formula in row 1?

Comment: Should `If .Cells(1, 22 * i + 3) <> 0 Then` not read `If .Cells(1, 22 * i + 13) <> 0 Then` i.e. the `i+3` should be `i+13` ?

Comment: This references cells right out to `$CGC$1` - you're using Excel 2007 onwards and not using Compatibility mode right?

Comment: This is an add-on to an existing code, where everything else works well. I do, The "If .Cells(1, 22 * i + 3) <> 0 Then" is also intended... I'm quite puzzled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only able to recreate the error you mention (Type Mismatch) by ensuring that one of the cells being checked (using cell `<>0`) contained an error. I simulated this by entering `=2/0` to create a divide by zero. (`#DIV/0!`)

The code below is your code but the two if statements are wrapped in another IF that checks that the cell isn't an error first. If it is, then it is NOT added to your `M3` formula. If you need it reworking to include it if it indeed contains an error instead, let me know and I'll re-draft.

```
Public Sub test3()
Dim i As Integer
With Sheet10
    .Cells(3, 13).Formula = "=0"
    For i = 1 To 100
        If Not (IsError(.Cells(1, 22 * i - 8))) Then
            If .Cells(1, 22 * i - 8) <> 0 Then
                .Cells(3, 13).Formula = .Cells(3, 13).Formula & "+" & .Cells(3, 22 * i + 2).Address
            End If
        End If
        If Not (IsError(.Cells(1, 22 * i + 13))) Then
            If .Cells(1, 22 * i + 13) <> 0 Then
                .Cells(3, 13).Formula = .Cells(3, 13).Formula & "+" & .Cells(3, 22 * i + 13).Address
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I found the error: my code was working but there was another problem in another sheet, with a date going rogue and changing into a #N/A for no reason I can find. Since I did a whole lot of other operations, it directly caused the error.

Comment: Understood. I think. Your rogue cell was being read (directly or indirectly) by your code. The code I've provided would fix this issue, so I think you can mark this as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest is to replace

```
 .Cells(3, 22 * i + 13).Address
```

with

```
Replace(.Cells(3, 22 * i + 13).Address,"$","")
```

Comment: Hi Harrassed, while I can see what you're proposing there, why would that help?

Comment: Ignore me, I've now seen the edit and can see they also asked how to remove the `$`.